# QQmlProperty::write is not working as expected

Tags: qt

I am new to Qt. I am trying to enable and disable the image from main window with 2 seconds delay but it is always taking the last property which i am setting. Please find my sample code below. I am expecting to be enable->disable->enable->disable->enable. but it is only enabled with delay.

I have tried to use all the properties.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
    return -1;
QObject *object = engine.rootObjects().first();

QObject *test= object->findChild<QObject*>("image");

if(test)
{
    QThread::msleep(2000);

    QQmlProperty::write(test, "visible", "false");
    added delay;

    QQmlProperty::write(test, "visible", "true");
    added delay;

    QQmlProperty::write(test, "visible", "false");
    added delay;

    QQmlProperty::write(test, "visible", "true");
}
return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: @halfer has a good point.  When something is urgent, I simply write in all caps to avoid this conundrum.

Comment: @Evan: BUT AH GOT EVEN MORE DOWN-DOOTS FOR YELLIN

Answer (score 0):

There is no `QThread` before a `QApplication` event loop is started (typically with [exec()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#exec)). So there is no pausing like you expect. Further, I'm pretty sure the `QQmlApplicationEngine` won't display anything until the main application loop has started.

You need to do your property changes either within `main.qml` (in QML code) or create some kind of persistent C++ object which does the changes after the main event loop has started, from inside the loop.

Also note that `QThread::msleep()` from the main thread will freeze the entire GUI. Using a timer might be more appropriate, if for example you want the user to be able to interact with, or exit, the application at all times.